# sysctl command returning info not asked about

Tags: io-redirection, sysctl

I want to `grep` a particular kernel setting as follows

```
$ sudo sysctl -a --ignore | grep -i max_map_count 2>/dev/null
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.docker0.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.stable_secret"
vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

Since I am both ignoring info about unknown keys (i.e. the `--ignore` option) **and** redirecting potential error output to `/dev/null`, what are these `reading jey` lines printed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are redirecting the stderr of the `grep` to /dev/null but the stderr messages are coming from `sysctl`. Try

```
sudo sysctl -a --ignore 2>/dev/null | grep -i max_map_count
```

Answer (score 5):

An explanation of the `stable_secrect` messages can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251401/cannot-read-key-net-ipv6-conf-all-stable-secret-in-sysctl). In short, the keys exist but are not initialized causing the message.

Concerning your actual command and goal, the pipe `|` only redirects `stdout` not `stderr` which is printed before the rest is sent to the pipe.
To have the expected behaviour you could use one of the commands as follows.

```
sudo sysctl -a --ignore 2> /dev/null | grep max_map_count
sudo sysctl -a --ignore 2>&1 | grep max_map_count
sudo sysctl -a --ignore |& grep max_map_count
```

Alternatively you also could use `find`.

```
find /proc/sys -name '*max_map_count*' -exec grep -H . "{}" \;
```

Better would be, as you already know what you are searching for.

```
sysctl vm.max_map_count
```